# SAS: Filling missing Dates

Tags: date, sas, missing-data

I have the following dataset:

| industry | start_year | first_date | no1 | no2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1990 | 200201 | 5 | 15 |  |
| A | 1990 | 200202 | 5 | 15 |  |
| A | 1990 | 200204 | 5 | 15 |  |
| A | 1990 | 200205 | 5 | 15 |  |

There are many sectors A,B,C,D and for each sector many starting years, e.g. 1990, 1991 etc.
It may be that industry x starts in 1990, but industry y only starts in 2005.
There is a "first date" for each industry and each start year, e.g. 200201, which is a numerical value but actually means 2002 January. The columns No1 and No2 are irrelevant, there are simply many more columns with numbers.

I would now like the column "First date" to always contain all months. For example, 200203 is missing in the table. I would now like a row to be added with branch A, start year 1990 and new first date 200203 (!). The other columns should all contain a zero.

My approaches so far:

```
/* All combinations existant */
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE all_combinations AS
   SELECT DISTINCT
      Branche,
      Anfangsjahr,
      Erstes Datum
   FROM
      have;
QUIT;

/* Extract year and month */
DATA all_combinations_year_month;
   SET all_combinations;
    jahr = int(Erstes Datum / 100);
    monat = mod(Erstes Datum, 100);

  /* mdy-function for date */
    sasDatum = mdy(monat, 1, jahr);
    format sasDatum date9.; /* Format */
run;
```

=>  I have now managed to convert the numerical value into a SAS date. But now I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you translate to English? I cannot figure out what your question is.  Variable names cannot have spaces in the middle of them.  Your SQL query will not work since you listed two names.  If you wanted to rename Erstes to Datum you would need to insert the keyword as between the two name.

Comment: I translated it since the answer from Stu is not possible for me because I have no SAS/ETS

Comment: How do you know which months are missing?  You added March, but why not June or July? START_YEAR also does not seem to have any role.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAS/ETS, this can be done quickly with `proc timeseries` /

Wenn Sie über SAS/ETS verfügen, kann dies mit `proc timeseries` schnell erledigt werden.

Data / Daten:

```
data have;
    input Branche$ Anfangsjahr Erstes_Datum:yymmn6. Zahl1 Zahl2;
    format Erstes_Datum date9.;
    datalines;
A 1990 200201 5 15
A 1990 200202 5 15
A 1990 200204 5 15
A 1990 200205 5 15
;
run;
```

```
proc timeseries data=have out=want;
    by branche;
    id Erstes_Datum interval=month align=beginning;

    var Anfangsjahr / setmissing=previous;
    var Zahl1-Zahl2 / setmissing=0;
run;
```

```
Branche Erstes_Datum    Anfangsjahr Zahl1   Zahl2
A       JAN2002         1990        5       15
A       FEB2002         1990        5       15
A       MAR2002         1990        0       0
A       APR2002         1990        5       15
A       MAY2002         1990        5       15
```

Comment: I dont have SAS ETS, so this doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I did it on my own:

```
DATA have_year_month;
   SET have;
    jahr = int(first_date / 100);
    monat = mod(first_date, 100);
run;

proc summary data=have_year_month nway;
  class branche start_year;
  var jahr;
  output out=template_years_min_max (drop=_:) min=Min_Startjahr max=Max_Startjahr;
run;

data template;
  set template_years_min_max;
  do jahr_num = Min_Startjahr to Max_Startjahr;
    do monat_num = 1 to 12;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data year_month_char;
set template;
jahr_char = put(jahr_num, z4.);
monat_char = put(monat_num, z2.);
run;

proc sql;
    create table date_char as 
    select *, cats(jahr_char,monat_char) as date_char from year_month_char;
quit;

data date_num;
    set date_char;
    first_date = input(date_char, 6.);
run;

Data want_all_dates;
    merge date_num have_year_month;
    by branche start_year first_date;
run;
``
```

Comment: Why not convert the yyy,ymm numbers into actual dates first?  Do you want to stop at the last actual date? Or do you always want to append empty months at the end of the last year?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. During all of my approaches I also had one with actual dates, but at some point I did not get further, so I made another approach and so on. I know that this is not the best or easiest way, but It works and my code needs about 10 sec to run, so for me it is very acceptable :-) and no, I dont want to append empty months at the end of the last year

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Proc Timeseries is the way to go here if SAS/ETS is available.

If not, here is a data step approach.

```
data have;
    input Branche$ Anfangsjahr Erstes_Datum:yymmn6. Zahl1 Zahl2;
    format Erstes_Datum date9.;
    datalines;
A 1990 200201 5 15
A 1990 200202 6 16
A 1990 200204 7 17
A 1990 200205 8 18
B 1990 200201 9 19
B 1990 200202 0 20
B 1990 200204 1 21
;
run;


data want;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : 'have');
      h.definekey('Branche', 'Erstes_Datum');
      h.definedata(all : 'Y');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   do until (last.Branche);
      set have;
      by branche;
      if first.Branche then from = Erstes_Datum;
      if  last.Branche then to   = Erstes_Datum;
   end;

   do until (from > to);
      call missing(Erstes_Datum);
      call stdize('replace','mult=',0,of Zahl:);
      Erstes_Datum = from;
      rc = h.find();
      output;
      from = intnx('month', from, 1, 's');
   end;

   keep Branche Anfangsjahr Erstes_Datum Zahl1 Zahl2;

run;
```

**Result:**

```
Branche Anfangsjahr Erstes_Datum Zahl1 Zahl2
A       1990        01JAN2002    5     15
A       1990        01FEB2002    6     16
A       1990        01MAR2002    0     0
A       1990        01APR2002    7     17
A       1990        01MAY2002    8     18
B       1990        01JAN2002    9     19
B       1990        01FEB2002    0     20
B       1990        01MAR2002    0     0
B       1990        01APR2002    1     21
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried almost the same, because chatgpt told me so. But: At the end I have the format DDMMYYYY in Erstes_Datum, but for merging with my original dataset, I need the Erstes_Datum from the new dataset to be the same like in the original one: YYYYMM (numeric!)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the merge part. Regardless, the format of the date variable should not matter. The underlying value is the same.

Comment: Aha allright, I did not know this

Answer (score 0):

So if you don't have SAS/ETS licensed then the simplest thing is to find the min/max date for each range and build a skeleton dataset the has every month between those two dates and zeros for the "other" variables.

Then you can just merge it back with the actual data and the zeros will be replaced with the actual data that exists.

Since the goofy YYY,YMM numeric values will sort in chronological order you don't have to convert them into dates until after you have found the first and last values for each group.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
  by Branche Anfangsjahr;
  var Erstes_Datum;
  output out=range min=start max=end;
run;

data skeleton ;
  set range;
  array others Erstes_Datum Zahl1 Zahl2 (3*0);
  retain Zahl1 Zahl2 ;
  start_date=mdy(mod(start,100),1,int(start/100));
  end_date=mdy(mod(end,100),1,int(end/100));
  do offset=0 to intck('month',start_date,end_date);
    date=intnx('month',start_date,offset);
    Erstes_Datum=100*year(date)+month(date);
    output;
  end;
  drop start end start_date end_date offset date _type_ _freq_;
run;

data want;
  merge skeleton have;
  by Branche Anfangsjahr Erstes_Datum;
run;
```

If you have a lot of variables you want to set to zero then you can take advantage of fact that variables that are read from input datasets are retained.  So change the top of the data step to:

```
data skeleton ;
  if 0 then set have;
  array others _numeric_;
  if _n_=1 then do offset=1 to dim(others);
    others[offset]=0;
  end;
  set range;
  start_date=mdy(mod(start,100),1,int(start/100));
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here ist, that in reality I dont have ohne Zahl1 and Zahl2, I have a lot of other columns which can change with the months...

Comment: Just put the list of variables into a macro variable.  Or don't bother and just leave the default as missing instead of zero.  Or add code in the merge step that sets all missing numeric variables to zero.  `array nums _numeric_; do over nums; nums=sum(nums,0); end;`

Comment: Allright, thank you